# Not fully working "Choose-when" conditional statement in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to make a conditional statement of the sort of "switch", so depending on the value of the `type` attribute in the XML file - I put a certain icon in the HTML and then I add the text. But if is not working fully... or not exactly as I want.

**The XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TreeView>
  <Parent text="Installation">
    <child text="Startup" type="video" file="startup.wmv" icon="c://user/desktop/blahblah.jpg"/>
    <child text="Getting there" type="video" file="gettingthere.wmv" icontPath="something"/>
    <child text="Steps" type="document" file="steps.docx" icon="asd"/>
    <child text="Pictures" type="presentation" file="pics.jpg" icon="dasdasdas"/>
  </Parent>
  <Parent text="Usage">
    <child text="Tilbud pane" type="video" file="tilbud.mwv" icon="asdasd"/>
    <child text="Report pane" type="document" file="report.docx" icon="gfdhd"/>
  </Parent>
</TreeView>
```

**The XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ul id="LinkedList1" class="LinkedList">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parent">
        <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
        <br/>
        <ul>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="child/@type = 'video'">
              <img src="play_icon.png" alt="play_video_icon" title="Video tutorial" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="child/@type = 'document'">
              <img src="word_icon.png" alt="text_document_icon" title="Text Document" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="child/@type = 'presentation'">
              <img src="powerpoint_icon.png" alt="powerpoint_icon" title="Power Point presentation" />
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="@text"/></li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I get ->

```
![Not correct.][1]
------------------------------------
```

And this is how I want it to look ->

```
![Correct.][2]
------------------------------------
```

I guess I am not ordering the conditional statement correctly, but I don't really have a clue how. So, any ideas how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ul id="LinkedList1" class="LinkedList">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parent">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
            <br/>
            <ul>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child[@type='video']">
        <li>
            <img src="play_icon.png" alt="play_video_icon" title="Video tutorial" />
            <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="child[@type='document']">
        <li>
              <img src="word_icon.png" alt="text_document_icon" title="Text Document" />
            <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="child[@type='presentation']">
        <li>
            <img src="powerpoint_icon.png" alt="powerpoint_icon" title="Power Point  presentation" />
            <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem with your approach is that you just generate one <img> for each parent.

If you prefer you can also use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ul id="LinkedList1" class="LinkedList">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parent">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
            <br/>
            <ul>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child">
        <li>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@type = 'video'">
                  <img src="play_icon.png" alt="play_video_icon" title="Video tutorial" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@type = 'document'">
                  <img src="word_icon.png" alt="text_document_icon" title="Text Document" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@type = 'presentation'">
                  <img src="powerpoint_icon.png" alt="powerpoint_icon" title="Power Point presentation" />
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yeah, I just realized my mistake (which is that I put the `choose-when` statement in the "Parent" template) and was thinking why not use the `choose-when` in the child template. And then you updated your answer. :) 
Thanks!

Comment: +1 for recommending the template matching approach instead of using `<xsl:choose>`